# sed - Search and Replace Multiple Line

Tags: bash, sed

I just learned today from an old question how SED works for single lines. But now I'm trying to do the same for multiple line (php file indented) and it is not working. How should that be done?

Code:

```
if ( empty( $donot_dump ) ) {
                return false;
```

replace to:

```
if ( empty( $donot_dump ) ) {
                return true;
```

Filename: class-prompt.php

Since this is a large file, there are TONS of return false; and return true;. So that's why I can't just make all returns trues or vice versa.

Comment: edit your question and explain why `sed 's/false/true/' file` is not enough for your case...

Comment: Done. It's a large file (and there will be more files with same "problem").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed '/if ( empty( $donot_dump ) )/ { N; s/false/true/ }' data
```

- `/regex/ cmd` will execute `cmd` only if the line matches the `regex`
- `{ cmds }` is a group of commands
- `N` command appends next line from a file to the pattern space
- `s/regex/replacement/` substitutes `regex` for `replacement`

In other words, this `sed` checks for your desired `if` statement. If it finds it, it executes a group of commands inside `{ ... }`. First command `N` appends the next line to the pattern space and the second command `s` substitutes `false` for `true`.

---

This solution works for [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/). As mentioned in SigmaPiEpsilon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030543/6176817), `N` command is not necessary here, use it with care. I used it in favor of `n` because it gives you options that I thought might come in handy. You can read more about this in [`sed` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiline-techniques) or in this [`sed` tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But you said: /regex/ cmd, but where is this cmd (outside "/ /")? Everything else I understood :)

Comment: @Diego It does not have to be a single command. You can also execute a group of commands with `{ cmds }`. So after `/ .. /` this `sed` executes two commands, `N` and `s/false/true`.

Comment: That is a very good explanation and very useful to all who end up here. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

A note of caution about `sed` multiline `N` and alternatives for people with similar problems. The multiline version of sed N command is not really necessary here. Since the text to be substituted is in the next line, the single line next (`n`) command is *sufficient*. It may also be *necessary* in cases where the **text to be substituted is also present in the original line**. This is because the multiline `N` command will pull next line into the pattern space and perform the substitution on the *combined* line. Single line next (`n`) command only acts on the next line. This is illustrated below where `N` performs incorrect substitution:

```
$ cat class_prompt.php
if ( empty( $donot_false_dump ) ) {
                return false;
$ sed '/if ( empty( \$donot_false_dump ) ) {/{ N; s/false/true/ }' class_prompt.php
if ( empty( $donot_true_dump ) ) {
                return false;
$ sed '/if ( empty( \$donot_false_dump ) ) {/{ n; s/false/true/ }' class_prompt.php
if ( empty( $donot_false_dump ) ) {
                return true;
```

The multiline N is necessary only when the search pattern extends over multiple lines.

This can also be done in perl. Like below

```
$ perl -pe 'if ($p) { s/false/true/ ; $p=0 } $p++ 
> if /if \( empty\( \$donot_false_dump \) \) {/ ' class_prompt.php
if ( empty( $donot_false_dump ) ) {
                return true;
```

Comment: This could be simply written in one sentence below PesaThe's answer in a comment.

Comment: No it couldn't. The distinction between the two commands is best seen through an example.

Comment: From the title *Search and Replace Multiple Line*, I concluded that multiline changes might be desired in the future, for example deletion. That's why I chose `N` and not `n` :) Of course if the changes are desired only on one line after a certain regex, `n` is enough.

Comment: @PesaThe `n` is not only enough but as my answer shows, may be necessary if the text to be substituted appears in original pattern as well.

Answer (score 0):

It should **not** be done with sed. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. When you do anything else with it you're using constructs that became obsolete in the 1980s when awk was invented and are usually non-portable and inefficient and can't be built upon to do anything else.

Given this input file:

```
$ cat file
foo
if ( empty( $donot_dump ) ) {
                return false;
bar
```

Using the currently accepted sed answer on OSX:

```
$ sed '/if ( empty( $donot_dump ) )/ { N; s/false/true/ }' file
sed: 1: "/if ( empty( $donot_dum ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'
```

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'f{sub(/false/,"true"); f=0} /if ( empty( $donot_dump ) )/{f=1} 1' file
foo
if ( empty( $donot_dump ) ) {
                return false;
bar
```

but in reality that whole approach is error-prone since it's using a regexp instead of string comparison and doing a partial match instead of full match and will only work for matching across 2 lines. If you're interested in a general, robust, solution for doing this type of task then post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for the first if statement and if it's found, replace the next line.

Regarding the substitution flags of Sed, g, replace all occurrences.

```
$ sed 's/test/another test/g' myfile
```

w flag: means write the results to a file.

```
$ sed 's/test/another test/2' myfile
```

I took these examples from this [sed tutorial](https://likegeeks.com/sed-linux/).